# Sort a list by id by using javascript

Tags: javascript, list, sorting, cordova

I'm making a phonegap app on iOS that requires sort a list by time
I tried add the time to the id of each li item and then sort based on the id

```
<ul id="test">
<li id="4112">blub</li>
<li id="1422">blaaah</li>
<li id="6640">hmmmm</li>
<li id="2221">one more</li>
</ul>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
$(function(){
var elems = $('#test').children('li').remove();
elems.sort(function(a,b){
    return (new Date(a.id) > new Date(b.id));
});
$('#test').append(elems);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3uYUq/1103/

I tried on chrome and it ran well . However, if I tried on phonegap app, the list is not sorted correctly . It doesn't follow any order. Any solution for this ? 
P/s: Someone said that on Safari it should be (new Date(a.id) - new Date(b.id)) on Safari but seems that it doesn't affect phonegap

Explain more about my phonegap code . This code retrive records from db and show it as list of items on html.

```
function getAllDeadlines_success(tx, results){

var len = results.rows.length;
//var s = "";
$('#allList').empty();
var tmpDueDate = '1900-01-01';
var tmpDueTime = '00:00';
for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    var allDeadline = results.rows.item(i);

    var deadlineDatePart = allDeadline.duedate.split('-');
    var deadlineTimePart = allDeadline.duetime.split(':');

    var newDate = new Date(deadlineDatePart[0], deadlineDatePart[1] - 1 , deadlineDatePart[2], deadlineTimePart[0], deadlineTimePart[1], 0, 0);         
    var notiDate = new Date(newDate - 86400*1000);
    //compare with current time
    var result = isLate(allDeadline.duedate, allDeadline.duetime).toString();
    if ( result == "true"){         
        $('#allList').append('<li id = "'+allDeadline.duedate+' '+allDeadline.duetime+'"><a href="#DeadlineDetail" id = "'+allDeadline.id+'" data-transition = "slide">'+ allDeadline.class +'<br>'+ allDeadline.duedate+'  '+ allDeadline.duetime+'<br>'+ allDeadline.description +'</a></li>');
        // window.plugin.notification.local.add({
        //  id : getRandomInt(0,99999), 
        //     message: 'Dont forget to complete: '+allDeadline.description+'',
        //     badge: 0,
        //     date: notiDate
        // });
    }
}

$(function(){
    var elems = $('#allList').children('li').remove();
    elems.sort(function(a,b){

        return (new Date(a.id) > new Date(b.id));
    });

    $('#allList').append(elems);
});
$("#allList").listview().listview('refresh');

}
```

Comment: The comparison function must return an integer. Your comparison function returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: Why are you converting IDs to `Date`?

Comment: I converted to date because I want to check if the date of the item a is later or before the date of the  item b so I can order them correctly

Comment: The IDs are small numbers like 4112 and 6640 -- what kinds of dates are those?

Comment: Because the content of the list contain a lot of information, include the date. But I don't know how to retrieve only the date inside the content so I use this trick to add the date into the ID so I can get the date value from ID and sort them

Comment: You can use `.text()` to get the contents of the LI, and use a regular expression to extract the date from this. Or you can put the date into a `data-date="2014-05-10"` attribute, then use `$(this).data("date")` to get it.

Answer (score 33):

The comparison function must return an integer. [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) checks whether it's negative, zero, or positive, and uses that to determine how the two elements should be ordered. So do:

```
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id - b.id;
});
```

Or, in modern [ES6 style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
elems.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
```